# Combine three markers in a single matplotlib legend item

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to plot square markers of two colors, with some of the markers of each color having an extra dot in the middle:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as ppl

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])

kw = dict(mew = 1, mec = 'k', ms = 10)

ppl.plot(x[::2], y[::2], 's', mfc = 'w', label = 'A', **kw)
ppl.plot(x[1::2], y[1::2], 's', mfc = [.8]*3, label = 'B', **kw)
ppl.plot(x[:2], y[:2], 'ks', mew = 0, ms = 3, label = 'special data')

ppl.legend()
ppl.show()
```

Which yields this:

[image: plot]

I would like to replace the small black marker used in thre third legend item by a combined marker with two side-by-side squares, one white and one grey, both with the central black mark, but so far all my attempts at hacking something with `matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple()` have been fruitless.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as ppl
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])

kw = dict(mew = 1, mec = 'k', ms = 10)

A, = ppl.plot(x[::2], y[::2], 's', mfc = 'w', label = 'A', **kw)
B, = ppl.plot(x[1::2], y[1::2], 's', mfc = [.8]*3, label = 'B', **kw)
sp, = ppl.plot(x[:2], y[:2], 'ks', mew = 0, ms = 3, label = 'special')

ppl.legend(
    [A, B, (A, B, sp, sp)],
    [_.get_label() for _ in [A, B, sp]],
    handler_map = {tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide = 2)},
    )

ppl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that creates custom legend.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])

kw = dict(mew = 1, mec = 'k', ms = 10)

# Each time you plot a kind of data, create a handle for future uses
white_rect, = plt.plot(x[::2], y[::2], 's', mfc = 'w', **kw)     # white
gray_rect, = plt.plot(x[1::2], y[1::2], 's', mfc = [.8]*3, **kw) # lightgray
black_dot, = plt.plot(x[:2], y[:2], 'ks', mew = 0, ms = 3)

# Create a custom legend from the handles
# Handles can be combined to get combined symbols
plt.legend([white_rect, gray_rect, (white_rect,black_dot), (gray_rect,black_dot)], \
                ["Attr A", "Attr B", "A Special", "B Special"], loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

[image: specleg]

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I don't know how to combine your last two lines into one, with two "special" square markers side-by-side, one white and one gray.